# Nextjs dyanmic router callback sometimes undefined

Tags: next.js

here is my folder stucture

```
shop
 - [categorySlug]
   - [productSlug]
     - index.tsx
   - index.tsx
index.tsx
```

graphql calling will be

**/shop/shoes/nike-1**

**/shop/jersey/jersey-1**

[categorySlug] index.tsx

```
export function ShopCategoryComponent({ products }): JSX.Element {
  const { query } = useRouter();
  const router = useRouter();
  const categorySlug = hasCategorySlug(query) ? query.categorySlug : undefined;

  const viewProductDeatails = useCallback(
    (productSlug) => {
      router.push(`/shop/${categorySlug}/${productSlug}`);
    },
    [router]
  );

  return (
    <section>
      {products.map((product) => (
        <div
          key={`${product.id}`}
          onClick={() => viewProductDeatails(product.slug)}
        >
          <h3>{product.name}</h3>
          <h3>{product?.$on['SimpleProduct'].price()}</h3>
          <img src={product?.$on['SimpleProduct'].image.sourceUrl()} />
        </div>
      ))}
    </section>
  );
}

export default function ShopCategory() {
  const { useQuery } = client;
  const { query } = useRouter();
  const { products } = useQuery();
  const categorySlug = hasCategorySlug(query) ? query.categorySlug : undefined;
  const generalSettings = useQuery().generalSettings;

  const setProducts = products({
    where: {
      categoryIn: categorySlug,
    },
  }).nodes;

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Menu />
      <main className='content content-single'>
        <ShopCategoryComponent products={setProducts} />
      </main>
      <Footer copyrightHolder={generalSettings.title} />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

when i click on the image it will then go to the productSlug page to show single product detail, it work sometimes, sometimes it will be undefined, like this.i wonder where i did wrong to cause this ?

**/shop/shoes/undefined**

Comment: Your `viewProductDeatails` callback depends on `categorySlug` and should therefore be added as a dependency.
But for quick debugging, just bind `router.push(\`/shop/${categorySlug}/${productSlug}\`); ` directly on the onClick event.
Could you also try checking if the particular product has the 'slug' property set?

Comment: yeah the productSlug is on it, it keep giving me the this error : Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. i know is map out key error but somehow i set it right still happening.

Comment: also i notice only the first time i click on the image have this problem, after back and reclick it, it will be ok again. let me see if i could reproduce a sample having the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it happen because of re-hydration and the categorySlug and productSlug have not get slug and it show undefined. also i mess up my variable categorySlug.

1.change

```
  const categorySlug = hasCategorySlug(query) ? query.categorySlug : undefined;
```

to

```
const categorySlug = query.categorySlug
```

2.add

```
export function ShopCategoryComponent({ products }): JSX.Element {
  const { query, isReady } = useRouter();
  const categorySlug = query.categorySlug;

  // pre-render page check, show loading if data havet get it.
  if (!isReady) {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Loading...</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }

}
```

now everything work fine now. thanks user8566930